# Making Keycloak (with LDAP) enforce password expiration

Tags: ldap, keycloak

I have Keycloak and LDAP in our environment. Our intention is that Keycloak is the only application that changes IAM information. LDAP is used only to extend IAM information to COTS applications that can't talk to Keycloak to get their needs met. (Vague, but yes, we have one.) So we're ok with LDAP *storing* the user password, but it will never change except through Keycloak.

I have one Keycloak realm configured for User Federation with LDAP. In that realm I want Keycloak to enforce password expiration after n days, among other policies. I have configured Keycloak to enforce Password Policies including password expiration. All password policies are enforced except expiration: nothing happens when a password is more than n days old.

My expectation is that Keycloak will enforce the policy that I have configured and make the user change their password when they attempt to log in after n days since the last password change.

Primary question: how can I make Keycloak enforce its own policy?

Secondary questions:

1. Where does Keycloak store the information about when a password was last set/modified? Is there some user attribute that I can query? Or can you point to a database table/column where it's stored? I can't see that information in the UI.
2. Do I need to pass that information to LDAP (perhaps so I can pass it back at some point)?
3. Do I need to configure a Mapper for password? (I don't have one configured now.)

User Federation Configuration:

| Setting Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| **Required Settings** |  |
| Import Users | ON |
| Edit Mode | WRITABLE |
| Sync Registrations | ON |
| **Advanced Settings** |  |
| Enable the LDAPv3 Password Modify Extended Operation | ON |
| Validate Password Policy | ON |
| Periodic Full Sync | OFF |
| Periodic Changed Users Sync | OFF |

Mappers:
| Attribute | Mapper Name |
| --- | --- |
| last name | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |
| creation date | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |
| modify date | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |
| email | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |
| groups | group-ldap-mapper |
| first name | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |
| username | user-attribute-ldap-mapper |